# No headers using Filehelpers FileHelperAsyncEngine in C#

Tags: c#, header, filehelpers

Can't seem to get the FileHelpers library to write headers since switching from FileHelperEngine to FileHelperAsyncEngine. I've called GetFileHeader() as per the docs. Any ideas?

```
<!-- language: c# -->

var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<ClaimModel>();
using (engine.BeginWriteFile(file))
{
    engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader();
    foreach (ClaimModel claim in claims)
    {
        engine.WriteNext(Utils.CleanStrings(claim));
    }
 }

   [FileHelpers.DelimitedRecord("|")]
    public class ClaimModel : Model
    {
        [FieldQuoted()]
        public string PolicyRef ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `HeaderText` before the `BeginWriteFile()`.

```
var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<ClaimModel>();
engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader();
using (engine.BeginWriteFile(file))
{
    foreach (ClaimModel claim in claims)
    {
        engine.WriteNext(Utils.CleanStrings(claim));
    }
}
```